# How would I input a range for a variable in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am currently in 10th grade and am in a computing class in visual basic. I am trying to set one of my variables, named Wrong1, as a range from negative infinity to 2, then 2 to infinity, so that if any answer other than two is inputted the screen would turn red, which I know how to do. I just dont know how to set that range for the variable. This is windows application Visual Basic 2010

Comment: What kind of Project?  WinForms maybe?  Possibly a Console app?  How are you entering a value for that variable?  If WinForms, maybe a TextBox?  If Console, I assume you are using Console.ReadLine()?  Give more details about your SETUP...

Comment: "Ok, also how do you set a textbox so that you can only type in numbers"  So probably WinForms.  Use a [NumericUpDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?view=netcore-3.1) control.  You can set a minimum and maximum value.

Comment: still, not enough technology stack tags

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in VB. Use custom class

```vb
public class AnswerValue

    private _max as integer
    private _min as integer
    private _answer as integer
   
    public property Max as integer
        get
            return _max
        end get
        friend set (value as integer) 'internal so you can set internally to dynamic value
            _max = value
        end set
    end property    

    public property Min as integer
        get
            return _min
        end get
        friend set (value as integer) 
            _min = value
        end set
    end property

    public property Answer as integer
        get
            return _answer
        end get
        set (value as integer) 
            if (value > _max & value < _min) then
                Throw New Exception("value must be between " & _min & " and " & _max)
             end if
            _min = value
        end set
    end property


end class


' USAGE
try
    dim av AnswerValue = _provider.GetAnswerValueFor(questionId)
    av.Answer = Convert.ToInt32(txtAnswer1.Text) 
catch es as Exception
    errorList.Add(ex.Message)
end try
```

Another way to achieve this is trough model Data annotation and validators

```vb
public class MyModel

    <Range(-100, 2)>
    public property Min as integer

end class
```

See what kind ranges different data types in VB have.

Comment: Ok, also how do you set a textbox so that you can only type in numbers

Comment: @YazeedHasan you have not added corresponding tags to answer this. Technology is different for every .net stack